# how to block all IP on SSH and allow only 1 or 2 adress with iptables?

Tags: ssh, block, iptables

how to block all connections/IP on SSH and allow only 1 or 2 address ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s [IP] --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

## iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j REJECT